# What are available software to cut multiple clips out of a single video?

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, mp4, mpeg

I'm looking for a software application to cut videos into multiple clips, typically by giving it the start and end time of the clip. Sometimes I need to cut about twenty clips from a single video, it becomes a cumbersome doing that with clip by clip approach.. so I need more quick solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/)  gets my vote for a free-but-sophisticated video editing suite. 
 The free version works beautifully for your needs.  I highly suggest learning the keystrokes to plow through a clip and cut out desired clips lickity-split.

Resolve runs on Linux, Mac, and Windows.  It compares with Adobe Premier as far as features and capability, especially if you pay for the Resolve Studio license, though that may not be necessary for the basic editing you mention.

There are a number a great tutorials on doing exactly what you want to do, using Resolve:

- [DaVinci Resolve 15: Getting Started with Basic editing & rendering
  in 17 min](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufHIv2gxAjg)
- [Tips to Edit Faster in Resolve 14 - DaVinci Resolve
  Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0a1KpWfux0)

This might be something better asked on the [Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/)